# How to measure the time between the creation the job on kubernetes by the user and the time of starting running this job on the node?

Tags: kubernetes, time, jobs

I am running a **job** with a kubernetes POD and I need to measure **the time between the creation the job by the user and the time of starting running this job on the node** .

I want to get it through some **api**.

Does anyone know how can I get it ?

Comment: Kubernetes job monitor maybe the closest https://github.com/pietervogelaar/kubernetes-job-monitor

Answer (score 1):

**Monitoring Kubernetes ( number of pending pods/jobs)**

Use the `kube-state-metrics` package for monitoring and a small Go program called `veneur-prometheus` to scrape the Prometheus metrics kube-state-metrics emits and publish them as statsd metrics to monitoring system.

For example, here’s a chart of the number of pending pods in the cluster over the last hour. Pending means that they’re waiting to be assigned a worker node to run on. You can see that the number spikes at 11am, because a lot of cron jobs run at the 0th minute of the hour in this case.

[image: Pending pods]

An example chart showing pending pods in a cluster over the last hour